# Line from another line objects

Tags: sql, line, spatial

Is there any way to extract some line from linestring where parallel line object is near?

The thing is I have multiple lines (some are intersecting the major line some not) that I have to somehow mark or extract from the major line. Big black line is the major, call it **Pipe**, and red is secondary line, call it **Road**.

My job is to mark or extract sections (that is shown between thin black lines) from Road on Pipe and create line from that sections. I have tried something with **STStartPoint** and **STEndPoint** then connect to line with **ShortestLineTo** but without any success. I'm new at spatial SQL and I really can't figure out how to do that.
[image]